# Finding gaps in serial numbers within model numbers in MySQL

Tags: mysql, serialization

Using MySQL, how can I best query a table of ~100,000 rows to find missing values in sequential serial numbers **within model numbers**. For example, finding missing serial numbers within clock radios (model #123 below) and within calculators (model #345 below).

The data looks like this:

MODEL#,  SERIAL#

---

123,        1
123,        2
123,        4
123,        5
345,      101
345,      104
345,      105
345,      106

The desired **output** would be

MODEL#, SERIAL#

---

123,        3
345,      102
345,      103

Note that the serial numbers have different starting values for each model number.

Thank you!

Comment: So, what SQL / code have you tried?

Comment: What would you do with the missing numbers

Answer (score 0):

It is rather hard to get the ones that are missing.  It is much easier to get the gaps.  So this returns the first missing serial and the number that are missing:

```
select t.serial + 1 as FirstMissing,
       (t.next_serial - t.serial) - 1 as numMissing
from (select t.*,
             (select t2.serial
              from data t2
              where t2.model = t.model and t2.serial > t.serial
              order by t2.serial asc
              limit 1
             ) as next_serial
      from data t
     ) t
where next_serial <> serial + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

To determine that something doesn't exist in that table, you can `LEFT JOIN` to that table and test whether the result `IS NULL`. For example, given any (model, serial) pair, you can construct the (model, serial) pair expected to follow a given one. This is same model number, with a serial number one bigger. Then `LEFT JOIN` the table to itself on the condition that the (model, serial) pair equals the expected one. For any missing serial number, each column in the self-joined alias `IS NULL`, so add a `WHERE` condition keeping only those rows.

The following will get you started. It identifies the *start* of each gap, though not all the numbers in the gap.

```
-- List all rows in table serials
-- 1. which aren't the highest for a given SKU, and
-- 2. for which the following serial number doesn't exist for the same SKU
SELECT ser1.sku, ser1.serial_num + 1 AS serial_num
FROM serials AS ser1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT sku, MAX(serial_num) AS serial_num
  FROM serials
  GROUP BY sku
) AS sermax
ON (ser1.sku = sermax.sku
    AND ser1.serial_num < sermax.serial_num)
LEFT JOIN serials AS ser2
ON (ser1.sku = ser2.sku
    AND ser1.serial_num + 1 = ser2.serial_num)
WHERE ser2.serial_num IS NULL
```

Output:

```
sku|serial_num
123|        3
345|      102
```

<sub>Code in this answer is dual licensed: [CC BY-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) or the [MIT License as published by OSI](http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT).</sub>

Comment: Thanks very much - I am working on rounding this out to find ALL missing serial_num values vs. the first missing one. If anyone has tips for this, it would be very appreciated.